# Existence of the second order derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Good morning to all. Could you please help me to prove that for the function f(x,y)=|x|y, the second order derivative of f, f''(x,y) exists at the point a=(0,2), using the definition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean. exactly? If $f$ is a function of two variables the notations $f'$ and $f''$ make no sense.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\frac{f(0+t,2)-f(0,2)}{t}=\frac{2|t|}{t}.$ Hence $ \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(0+t,2)-f(0,2)}{t}$ does not exist. Therefore $f_x(0,2)$ does not exist.

Conclusion: $f$ is not differentiable at $a=(0,2),$ hence the  second order derivative of $f$ at $a$ does not exist.